How to solve the equation: $x^{2}+2^{x}=6$ and $x^{2}=2^{x}$
How to solve the equations
$1)$ $x^{2}+2^{x}=6$
$2) x^{2}=2^{x}$
For the $2^{nd}$ equation the values of $x$ are $2,4$.
It is mentioned that $$x^{2}=2^{x}$$
Which implies $$2\log(x)=x\log(2)$$
Which implies $$\frac{\log(x)}{x}=\frac{\log(2)}{2}$$
Which implies $$\log x^{\frac{1}{x}}=\log 2^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Which means $x=2$.
Similarly by the trial and error method $x=4$ is also a solution for the $2^{nd}$ equation.
But Desmos is giving one negative value of $x$ too. That is $x=-0.766$
How to find this negative value of $x$ for the equation $2^{x}=x^{2}$ ?
And for the $1^{st}$ equation how to find an approximate value of $x$ ?
Like, if I write the equation to be $x^{2}=6-2^{x}$ or $2^{x}=6-x^{2}$ then also I can't find any shortcuts.
Again, I was thinking for Applying Newton- Raphson method to find $x$.
But the problem is that to apply Newton Raphson method, I should know a value of $x$.
That is according to the Desmos, there are $2$ solutions for $x^{2}+2^{x}=6$
But I don't know any one value of $x$. So, I can't apply Newton Raphson Method also.
Please help me out with these $2$ equations to find the values of $x$.

The $1^{st}$ equation I discovered and the $2^{nd}$ one is from the book.

You should say where this question came from i.e., the book and the subject matter that you are studying. Otherwise you may be asked to write a computer program that finds a numerical solution.

Are these two different questions?  Please ask one question at a time.

R. S. AGGARWAL book. @Mike. Also these are $2$ different questions. Actually since both are bit similar, so I asked two in one.

For the equation 2, you make an error, it should be
$$\iff \frac{\log(|x|)}{x} = \frac{\log(2)}{2} $$ and because of that, you missed the negative solution.

Please, ask one question per post.

Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function answer your question?

2 equation, a way $ f(x)=x^2+2^x-6 \Rightarrow f'(x)= 2x+ln 2 \ 2^x \Rightarrow f''(x)=2+ln^2 2 \ 2^x $
Then $ f''(x)>0 $, f'(x) is growing in R, there is only one solution f'(x)=0, then f(x) is decreasing but then it increases. Therefore f has two solutions.
Observing change of sign of f the intervals of the solutions are [-3,-2] and [1,2]
you can use bisection method, for find the solutions

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
